# How to prevent Doctrine from dropping computed/generated column

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb

I use MariaDB for a Symfony project and have setup a computed column with:

```
ALTER TABLE history_event ADD quote_status_change SMALLINT AS (JSON_VALUE(payload, '$.change_set.status[1]'));
```

When I run Doctrine migrations with `bin/console doctrine:schema:update`, the computed column is dropped, probably because it doesn't appear anywhere in the `HistoryEvent` entity class.

How can I prevent Doctrine from dropping computed columns when I run migrations ?

Comment: I'm afraid you might be out of luck: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6434

Comment: @malarzm If you post this as an answer, I will gladly accept it. It was the right answer. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Use migrations for the win  stop using the schema tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you might be out of luck, there is an open feature request but it's not implemented yet: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6434

Answer (score 4):

I solved this in doctrine 2.10 using the [OnSchemaColumnDefinition Event](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/events.html#onschemacolumndefinition-event).  My code looked something like this:

```
public function onSchemaColumnDefinition(SchemaColumnDefinitionEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    if ($eventArgs->getTable() === 'my_table') {
        if (!in_array($eventArgs->getTableColumn()['field'], ['id', 'column_1', 'column_2'])) {
            $eventArgs->preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I'm using Symfony 4.2 so I set the event listener class up [as per](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#configuring-the-listener-subscriber).

Comment: this should be the answer, worked for us as well on Symfony 3.4. For the sake of completeness, this is the yaml part: 
framework.listener.schema:
        class: SymfonyBundle\EventListener\DoctrineSchemaListener
        tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onSchemaColumnDefinition}